# Cardinality with a Bijection

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Suppose that $a, b \in \mathbb{R}: a<b$.  Show that $(a, b) ≈ℝ$ by finding a bijection between the sets.

I think this might work but am not certain: $g(x) = \frac{2x-b-a}{b-a}$

I was also told to give a formula for my function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is g(x) supposed to map from R to (a,b) or from (a,b) to R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to find a strictly increasing function on $(a,b)$ with vertical asymptotes at $x = a$ and $x = b$. Recall that $y = \tan x$ is strictly increasing on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and has vertical asymptotes at $x = \pm \pi/2$ (which are $\pi$ apart, centred at $0$). Thus, we should horizontally stretch the function by $\frac{b-a}{\pi}$, then horizontally translate by $\frac{a + b}{2}$ to the right. This yields:
$$
y = \tan \left( \frac{\pi}{b-a} \left(x - \frac{a + b}{2}\right) \right)
$$

Comment: Thank you, would this be enough to show this Cardinality by a bijection?

Answer (score 0):

How about
$$g(x)=\frac1{x-a}+\frac1{x-b}$$
for $x\in(a,b)$?

(It should be proven that $g$ is decreasing).

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work. $g(a)=-1$ and $g(b)=1.$ But you can use it to get

$$(a,b)\to (-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}, x\to \pi/2g(x) \to \tan (\pi/2g(x)).$$

Comment: I am confused here.

Comment: Your function gives a bijection between $(a,b)$ and $(-1,1).$ If you multiply by $\pi/2$ you have a bijection between $(-1,1)$ and $(-\pi(2,\pi/2).$ Now, the tangent function gives a bijection between that interval and the real line.